# Change javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a function in theme.js file

```
 $('.open_copy').click(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        var copy = that.prev();

        that.parents('.asset').find('.cover').click();
        copy.css('opacity', 0).show();
        if (copy.children('.copy_content').data('jsp')) {
            copy.children('.copy_content').data('jsp').destroy();
        }
        var height = copy.children('.copy_content').css({height: ''}).height();

        if (height < that.parents('.asset').height() - 37) {
            var top = (that.parents('.asset').height() - height)/2;
            top = top < 37 ? 37 : top;
            copy.children('.copy_content').css({'margin-top': top});
        } else {
            copy.children('.copy_content').css({'margin-top': '', height: that.parents('.asset').height() - 37}).jScrollPane();
        }

        if (!that.parents('.asset').find('.close_copy').length) {
            that.prev().append('<a href="#" class="close_copy">Close</a>');
        }

        copy.animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 500);

        that.fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    });
```

I need to change opacity value to 0.9 but i don't have access to the theme.js file. There is any way i can change/alter this function by adding a function in the html page?

```
copy.animate({ 'opacity' : 1 }, 500);
```

Comment: You will have to overwrite it. First you have to unbind the click event, Then rewrite the whole function with your new values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can remove the click handler that code sets up, and then add your own with identical code except for the `1` => `0.9` change.

To remove that code's click handler (and all others), use [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off):

```
$('.open_copy').off('click');
```

...and then of course add your own, new `click` handler.

So in total, then, you'd want this code (**after** the `script` tag including `theme.js`, so this code runs after that code):

```
$('.open_copy').off('click').click(function(){ // <== Changed
    var that = $(this);
    var copy = that.prev();

    that.parents('.asset').find('.cover').click();
    copy.css('opacity', 0).show();
    if (copy.children('.copy_content').data('jsp')) {
        copy.children('.copy_content').data('jsp').destroy();
    }
    var height = copy.children('.copy_content').css({height: ''}).height();

    if (height < that.parents('.asset').height() - 37) {
        var top = (that.parents('.asset').height() - height)/2;
        top = top < 37 ? 37 : top;
        copy.children('.copy_content').css({'margin-top': top});
    } else {
        copy.children('.copy_content').css({'margin-top': '', height: that.parents('.asset').height() - 37}).jScrollPane();
    }

    if (!that.parents('.asset').find('.close_copy').length) {
        that.prev().append('<a href="#" class="close_copy">Close</a>');
    }

    copy.animate({ 'opacity' : 0.9 }, 500);  // <== Changed

    that.fadeOut(500);
    return false;
});
```

You'll want to check for side effects (for instance, if there's other code that also sets up `click` handlers on those elements, since the code above will remove them, too).

Comment: Thanks TJ, the problem now is that the opacity goes to 0.9 but then goes back to 0.

Comment: @BogdanS: Strange, I'm not seeing anything in that code which would cause that.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript support override of variables and methods.
You should declare an overriding JS script AFTER import of Theme.js file.
So, you can exactly copy/paste that function changing only the values you need to.

Note that, as that function is an event binding, you may need to unbind the onclick event first.